# Prove that if the right coset $Hg$ equals *some* left coset of $H$ in $G$ then it equals the left coset of $gH$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H \le G$ and let $g \in G$. Prove that if the right coset $Hg$ equals *some* left coset of $H$ in $G$ then it equals the left coset of $gH$ and $g$ must be in $N_G(H)$.

I see that, if $hg \in Hg$, then $(hg)^{-1} = g^{-1} h^{-1} \in g^{-1}H$. And, since the number of left cosets equals the number right cosets, it seems plausible that there must be a bijection between $gH$ and $Hg$ (presumably of the form $gH \mapsto g^{-1}H$); but getting to $gH = Hg$ is escaping me.

Since I've yet to use the fact that the right coset $Hg$ equals *some* left coset of $H$ in $G$, I assume that that's the key. So, suppose $Hg = aH$ for some $a \in G$. Then, $hg = ah'$, for some $h' \in H$. Well, this doesn't tell me much... I've got that $g \in h^{-1}aH$, $a\in Hg(h')^{-1}$, but I'm not seeing much else.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: If two left cosets share an element (have nonempty intersection), then they are equal.

Comment: Sigh... that didn't do it for me...

Comment: If $Hg=xH$ we have that $g\in Hg = xH$.  So $g$ is in both $gH$ and $xH$.

Comment: But how is $g$ in $gH$?

Comment: Since $H$ is a subgroup, $e\in H$ (where $e$ is the group identity element).  So $g=ge\in gH$.

Comment: Oh, wow. Yep, it sure it is. That's embarrassing. Thank you.